# Confusion interpreting ANOVA sum of squares

Tags: r, anova, interaction, interpretation

I've always had trouble understanding ANOVA (regressions make much more sense to me, and are more powerful, so why bother with ANOVA?).  But I've been reading a book on the history of the gene-environment interaction debate, and I wanted to make sure I understand how ANOVA works.

So let's construct some simulated data.  Two genotypes, represented by 0 and 1, 500 of each.  Two environments, represented by 0 and 1, 500 of each.  (For convenience, I'll paste all the code into a single block at the end.)

```
library(tidyverse)

half_n = 500
dataf = data.frame(env = rep(c(0, 1), half_n),
                   gene = c(rep(0, half_n), rep(1, half_n)))
```

To get a really dramatic interaction, let's say we want 20% of the variance due to genotype, another 20% due to environment, and 50% due to the gene-environment interaction. That leaves 10% due to noise.

[Edits start here]

Let 
$$y = \beta_g g + \beta_e e + \beta_{ge} g \times e + \epsilon,$$
where $g$ codes the genotype, $e$ codes the environment, and $\epsilon$ is noise.

Then, since everything is uncorrelated, 
$$Var(y) = \beta_g^2 Var(g) + \beta_e^2 Var(e) + \beta^2_{ge} Var(g \times e) + Var(\epsilon).$$
Note that $Var(g)$ is the the variance in genotype, $\beta_g^2 Var(g)$ is the contribution of genotype to total variance, and $\frac{\beta_g^2 Var(g)}{Var(y)}$ is the fractional contribution of genotype to total variance.  (Maybe the problem is that there's some correlation I'm not accounting for in this step?)

Since we have 500 each of the two genotypes and two environment types, $Var(g) = Var(e)$.  Set $\beta_g^2 = \beta_e^2 = .2$, and $Var(\epsilon) = .1 Var(g)$.  $Var(g \times e) \neq Var(g)$, so set
$$ \beta^2_{ge} = .5 \frac{Var(g)}{Var(g \times e)}.$$

Then $Var(y) = (.2 + .2 + .5 + .1) Var(g) = Var(g)$, and the fractional contribution of genotype to total variance is $$\frac{.2 Var(g)}{Var(y)} = .2$$, as desired.  To put that into code:

[Edits end here]

```
v_g = .2
v_e = .2
v_ge = .5
v_err = 1 - (v_g + v_e + v_ge)

set.seed(42)
dataf$err = rnorm(2*half_n, sd = sd(dataf$gene))
dataf$y = with(dataf, 
    sqrt(v_g)*gene + sqrt(v_e)*env + 
    sqrt(v_ge)*sd(gene)/sd(gene*env)*gene*env + 
    sqrt(v_err)*err)
```

Then do the ANOVA.  As I understand ANOVA, "sum of squares" is the variance associated with a given term, e.g., $Var(\beta_g g) = \beta_g^2 Var(g)$.  These add up to the total variance, so the `summary` step extracts these values and converts them into fractions of the total variance.

```
anova1 = aov(y ~ gene*env, data = dataf)
anova1
# Call:
#   aov(formula = y ~ gene * env, data = dataf)
# 
# Terms:
#   gene       env  gene:env Residuals
# Sum of Squares  183.52553 183.10113  43.16575  25.11250
# Deg. of Freedom         1         1         1       996
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.1587871
# Estimated effects may be unbalanced

summary(anova1)[[1]]$`Sum Sq` %>% {./sum(.)}
# [1] 0.4219900 0.4210142 0.0992533 0.0577425
```

So the ANOVA finds `gene` and `env` both contribute about 42% of the total variance, the interaction contributes about 10%, and noise contributes the remaining 6%.  Evidently I'm getting something very wrong, but I'm not sure what.

---

All the code in one block:

```
library(tidyverse)

half_n = 500

v_g = .2
v_e = .2
v_ge = .5
v_err = 1 - (v_g + v_e + v_ge)

set.seed(42)
dataf = data.frame(env = rep(c(0, 1), half_n),
                   gene = c(rep(0, half_n), rep(1, half_n)))
dataf$err = rnorm(2*half_n, sd = sd(dataf$gene))
dataf$y = with(dataf, sqrt(v_g)*gene + sqrt(v_e)*env + 
    sqrt(v_ge)*sd(gene)/sd(gene*env)*gene*env + 
    sqrt(v_err)*err)

anova1 = aov(y ~ gene*env, data = dataf)
anova1
summary(anova1)[[1]]$`Sum Sq` %>% {./sum(.)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing the mean with the variance.

You specify the model $y = v_g 1_g + v_e 1_e + v_{ge} 1_{ge} + \epsilon$, where the $v$'s are what you define above and $1_g$, for instance, represents the $(0,1)$ covariate on the gene.

Notice that the regression

> lm(y ~ gene*env + 0, data = dataf)$coefficients %>% {./sum(.)}

recovers

> ```
>  gene         env     gene:env
> ```
>
> 0.2571027   0.2565234    0.4863739

which are noise corrupted version of the slopes $v$ that you define above.

This is because, classically, regression output describes the mean, while ANOVA outputs describes the variance. What you're reporting through the ANOVA table is a sequential partition of the variance that we can attribute to each covariate. For more about this, I would check out Type I sums of squares.

---

From my understanding, there seems to be some confusion about sample variance vs true variance too (in the context of regression). To make things clear, I'll try to give a brief explanation of a nice way to think about regression that should make these ideas more transparent.

Let $$y_{ijk} = \mu_{ij} + \epsilon_{k(ij)},$$ where $(i,j)$ denotes the gene, environment level, which gives the mean and $k$ denotes the replicate within $(i,j)$. A linear model, which we're using, posits that $\mu_{ij}$ is a linear function of the covariates: this is true for us, since $$\mu_{ij} = v_0+v_e 1_{i=1} + v_g 1_{j=1} + v_{ge} 1_{i=1, j=1} = 
\begin{cases}
 v_0 & if & i=0, j=0 \\
 v_0+v_e & if & i=0, j=1\\
 v_0+v_g & if & i=1, j=0\\
 v_0+v_g + v_e + v_{ge} & if & i=1,j=1,
\end{cases}
$$ for $v_0$ being the intercept.
Further, in this regression setting, we're assuming that $\epsilon_{k(ij)} \sim_{iid} \mathcal{N} (0, \sigma^2)$. You've defined $\sigma=v_{err}$.

The mean is $\mu_{ij}$ and the (conditional) variance $\sigma = v_{err}$ is associated with the error term $\epsilon$. This is what I mean by confusing the mean and the variance. Further, writing the regression in terms of each observation $i,j,k$ should make it more clear that we shouldn't be computing the sample variance of, for instance, the gene $0,1$ measurements.

From this perspective, please let me know further questions you have related to your post. This perspective is nice, and it allows quantities of interest to be neatly worked out in terms of matrices. A textbook that gives a nice account of this is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012508465X), by Moser. This textbook was used as a reference in a course for junior/senior applied statistics students for a course I TA'd. I think the first few chapters give a well ordered account of the material.

---

I think I should add brief comparison of the current two answers since they're fairly different: from my perspective, martijn provides a solid account of sequential sums of squares (which is great, by the way; I earlier tried to link to a good explanation of them on stackexchange, but couldn't find one), but I don't think that's the primary source of your question, so I'm trying to focus more on my (perhaps totally wrong!) guess of the source of confusion.  So far that's this mean vs. variance thing. Let me know if you think I'm missing the mark!

Comment: The problem is that, on the one hand, I constructed the example to partition the variance in a certain way, and on the other hand, the ANOVA results aren't close at all to that intended construction.  I've edited the question to explain the intended construction in more detail.

Comment: My answer is intended to convey that those $v$'s (or $\beta$'s) are in the mean, while the sums of squares are related to the variance. So your example doesn't partition the variance in a certain way. To comment on your edit, you're assuming that your covariates are random, while the $r$ functions you're using are assuming they're fixed. That is, $var(g) = var(e) = var(g\times e) = 0$.

Comment: First, what exactly do you mean when you say that something is "in the mean" vs. "related to the variance"?  And second, you're saying that, for example, `aov` assumes that the variance of `gene` is 0?

Comment: I'll describe the first one in a bit: it'll take more time. For your second one: yes, it's treating the covariate as fixed

Comment: @DanHicks I've made the edits. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide more detail. So you're saying ANOVA doesn't analyze the unconditional variance Var(y), but instead the conditional variance Var(y|x) given the covariates?

Comment: @DanHicks Yes: the big idea behind ANOVA is that it partitions the estimate for the conditional variance. Your sums of squares are scaled versions of such a partition, which does not correspond to the slope estimates provided by the regression

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the basic idea much better now.  Which particular chapters of Moser cover ANOVA?

Comment: Looking through that Moser book, I now think they build up a lot of material that (while useful and important) are only peripheral. Instead, I think you should read chapter 2 of Agresti's glm book (https://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Linear-Generalized-Probability-Statistics/dp/1118730038). After going through that chapter, I think you will have a solid understanding of the ideas behind least squares (regression and anova), which is what you most directly seem to be looking for.

Comment: As an aside, the preview of the book on that amazon page (which is why I'm linking to amazon) has very different (and much worse) formatting than the actual book. Also, in particular, I think you should focus on chapters 2.1-2.4. Note, the first paragraph or so of the chapter talks about things in the language of GLMs, but the rest of the chapter is firmly in the setting of linear models

Answer (score 2):

The aov() function adds the terms in stepwise order and presents the change in the sum of squares of nested models and whether this is significant in each step.

Now after already having added the 'gene' and 'env' terms (which correlate with the cross effect), they sort of "steal" some of the effect that the cross-term would have had. In other words the 'gene' and 'env' main effect terms are already a very good model and take a part of the effect from the cross term.

To imagine this more intuitively with a different hypothetical case:
If the main effects would have been zero, and the cross effect would be the only effect. In that case you could still device a significant model with only main effect terms, because the main effect terms will partly correlate with the cross effect. Then, adding the cross effect when the main effects are already in the model, will result in a smaller improvement of the model, compared to the situation when the cross effect is added to a model without the main effect terms.

See the following code that compares the models more explicitly.

```
> anova(lm(y ~ 0, data = dataf),lm(y ~ 0+I(gene*env), data = dataf))
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ 0
Model 2: y ~ 0 + I(gene * env)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1   1000 853.84                                  
2    999 121.69  1    732.15 6010.6 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> anova(lm(y ~ 0+gene+env, data = dataf),lm(y ~ 0+gene+env+I(gene*env), data = dataf))
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ 0 + gene + env
Model 2: y ~ 0 + gene + env + I(gene * env)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq    F    Pr(>F)    
1    998 82.845                                
2    997 25.113  1    57.733 2292 < 2.2e-16 ***
--- 
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And see also what happens if you would change the order in the aov() function.

```
> summary(aov(y ~ 0+I(gene*env)+gene+env, data = dataf))
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
I(gene * env)   1  732.2   732.2   29067 <2e-16 ***
gene            1   48.4    48.4    1921 <2e-16 ***
env             1   48.2    48.2    1913 <2e-16 ***
Residuals     997   25.1     0.0                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> summary(aov(y ~ 0+gene+env+I(gene*env), data = dataf))
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
gene            1  578.5   578.5   22967 <2e-16 ***
env             1  192.5   192.5    7642 <2e-16 ***
I(gene * env)   1   57.7    57.7    2292 <2e-16 ***
Residuals     997   25.1     0.0                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't think that you will see your original mix of 2:2:5:1 ratios back in the sum of squares of the anova, which will look at differences in variance of the model for changes between two models. And it should be calculated from the coefficients in the full linear model.

```
> model<-lm(y ~ 0+gene+env+I(gene*env), data = dataf)
> var((coefficients(model)[1]*dataf$gene))/2
[1] 0.02422251
> var((coefficients(model)[2]*dataf$env))/2
[1] 0.02411349
> var((coefficients(model)[3]*dataf$env*dataf$gene))/5
[1] 0.02600566
> var(model$residuals)
[1] 0.02513795
```

However, if you look at the change of the sum of squares of the residual, then you come reasonably close when you look at dropping one of the terms from the complete model.

```
> model<-lm(y ~ 0+gene+env+I(gene*env), data = dataf)
> drop1(model,scope=~gene+env+I(gene*env))
Single term deletions

Model:
y ~ 0 + gene + env + I(gene * env)
              Df Sum of Sq    RSS     AIC
<none>                     25.113 -3678.4
gene           1    48.397 73.509 -2606.3
env            1    48.179 73.292 -2609.3
I(gene * env)  1    57.733 82.845 -2486.8
```

The 48.397 : 48.179 : 57.733 : 25.113 is not the same as 2:2:5:1. But that is due to the previously explained effect. If you take the full model then you do not add a factor 2 or 5 to the residual sum of squares by leaving out the terms gene/env or gene$*$env, because the terms can make up for each other. Say you leave out 'gene$*$env' then the coefficients for gene and env will increase a bit to make up for the loss of the cross term, and in that way the RSS will only increase by 57.733 and not the five times 25.113.

See the example in terms of linear models. The coefficients for the main effects increase if you leave out the cross-effect term (and hence the variance described by these model terms increases).

```
> lm(y ~ 0+gene+env+I(gene*env), data = dataf)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + gene + env + I(gene * env), data = dataf)

Coefficients:
         gene            env  I(gene * env)  
       0.4400         0.4390         0.8323  

> lm(y ~ 0+gene+env, data = dataf)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + gene + env, data = dataf)

Coefficients:
  gene     env  
0.7174  0.7164
```

---

A fun example

Here you see that the whatever gets first becomes the significant factor. In this case the cross effect is still somewhat detected by the main effect. But in some cases you are less lucky and the term at the end, which may be very significant, gets unnoticed due to all the previous terms reducing the strength of the model.

```
> v_g = .0
> v_e = .0
> v_ge = .005
> v_err = 1 - (v_g + v_e + v_ge)
> 
> set.seed(42)
> dataf = data.frame(env = rep(c(0, 1, 2, 3), half_n),
+                    gene = c(rep(0, half_n), rep(1, half_n), rep(2, half_n), rep(3, half_n)))
> dataf$err = rnorm(2*half_n, sd = sd(dataf$gene))
> dataf$y = with(dataf, sqrt(v_g)*gene + sqrt(v_e)*env + 
+                  sqrt(v_ge)*sd(gene)/sd(gene*env)*gene*env + 
+                  sqrt(v_err)*err)
> 
> summary(aov(y ~ 0+I(gene*env)+gene+env, data = dataf))
                Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
I(gene * env)    1    9.0   9.015   7.209 0.00732 **
gene             1    0.3   0.281   0.225 0.63551   
env              1    0.3   0.306   0.245 0.62066   
Residuals     1997 2497.3   1.251                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> summary(aov(y ~ 0+gene+env+I(gene*env), data = dataf))
                Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
gene             1    7.4   7.421   5.934 0.0149 *
env              1    0.2   0.180   0.144 0.7042  
I(gene * env)    1    2.0   2.001   1.600 0.2060  
Residuals     1997 2497.3   1.251                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: If ANOVA isn't supposed recover the 2:2:5:1 ratio used to construct `y`, then apparently I'm even more deeply confused about what its purpose and interpretation than I thought.  Order effects also seem to be inconsistent with all of the instructional pages I'm finding online (for calculating 2-way ANOVA by hand); though those pages are also inconsistent with each other.  Maybe I should just ask for a textbook recommendation instead.

Comment: ANOVA is not about the variance related to the (original) separate model terms. That would be meaningless. You currently have four groups (2x2) which you partition in three different way, split by g=1 vs 0, split by e=1 vs 0 and split by g*e=1 vs 0. This is arbitrary and only made such because it relates to a research question. In my example I show that the cross term (g=1 and e=1) is more significant, but you could have chosen three other terms as well. The point is to test whether a particular model (ie 2 main + 1 cross) is significant, and not necessarily to look at the terms independently.

Comment: If I understand things a little better now, this page unpacks the `aov` black box a little more:  http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~fscholer/anova.php